# How to update address in list from completion handler in CLGeocoder geocodeAddressString()

Tags: swift, swift3, geolocation

I have a list of addresses I want to update and also add the lat long to. After reading in the list of addresses into an array I call the geocodeAddressString function in CLGeocoder.

In the completion handler how do I know which index in the address list was used to make the geocodeAddressString call?

Basically I would like to set

```
locations[1].MailAddr1 = placemark.name
locations[1].MailCity = placemark.locality
locations[1].MailState = placemark.administrativeArea
locations[1].MailZip = placemark.postalCode
locations[1].lat = placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude
locations[1].long = placemark.location!.coordinate.longitude
```

How do I get back to the locations array and also how do I know the index, in this example = 1?

I am hoping to be able to loop through the entire array.

```
    let locations = ReadCSV()

    let address = locations[1].MailAddr1 + ", " + locations[1].MailCity + ", " + locations[1].MailState + ", " +  locations[1].MailZip + ", " + locations[1].MailCountry

    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if((error) != nil){
            print("Error", error)
        }
        if let placemark: CLPlacemark = placemarks?.first {
            let name = placemark.name
            let address = placemark.thoroughfare
            let locality = placemark.locality
            let zip = placemark.postalCode
            let subLocality = placemark.subLocality
            let country = placemark.country

            let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate
            let location: CLLocation = placemark.location!


        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume your location is a class:

go over your array and later use this location:

```
for location in locations { 

//...
    // in your completion handler
    location.lat = placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude
//...
}
```

PS: if location is a struct then you need to do a different strategy

Answer (score 0):

try to make function and sent each location as inout parameter

Example:

```
for location in locations {

 setAddressOflocation(location)

}

func getAddressOflocation (locationObject : inout  CLLocation) {

let address = locationObject.MailAddr1 + ", " + locationObject.MailCity + ", " + locationObject.MailState + ", " +  locationObject.MailZip + ", " + locationObject.MailCountry

let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
    if((error) != nil){
        print("Error", error)
    }
    if let placemark: CLPlacemark = placemarks?.first {
        let name = placemark.name
        let address = placemark.thoroughfare
        let locality = placemark.locality
        let zip = placemark.postalCode
        let subLocality = placemark.subLocality
        let country = placemark.country

        let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate
        let location: CLLocation = placemark.location!

        locationObject.lat = placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude
        locationObject.long = placemark.location!.coordinate.longitude

    }
})
}
```